# How to reuse data when updating Token using StateMachine

Tags: nft, plutus-pioneer-program, minting, decentralized-applications, statemachines

I'm currently creating a social network-like Dapp on plutus, and I've come across something I don't understand.

My Dapp, for example, is NFT(for own identity)->RFT(for sell own content)->NFT(for some other user)->MFT(NFT with some validator). In the case of this diagram, the transaction exists at the pointers between the various tokens.

[image: transtate token into token]

What I want to do is to concatenate multiple MintingPolicies with different conditions in a one-way fashion while maintaining the data.

Most of sample code Lars written in the Plutus-Pioneer-Program has only one validator or MintingPolicy in each file.

When I create a transaction from off-chain, I want to bring in the data used in the previous MintingPolicy for the new MintingPolicy.

What is the best way to use StateMachine when I want to do this? For example, in the StateMachine.hs code, you can use

```
gameDatum :: TxOut -> (DatumHash -> Maybe Datum) -> Maybe GameDatum
gameDatum o f = do
    dh <- txOutDatum o
    Datum d <- f dh
    PlutusTx.fromData d
```

Do we need to repeat this process of searching for Datum I want to keep with the TxOut argument of a specific transaction?

I already know that UTxO is never rewritten, but rather that similar UTxOs are generated over and over again, so that it feels as if a single UTxO is being updated.

Lars says that StateMachine is in one (e)UTxO. So, is it like an empty bucket that can be injected with new data, deleted, or updated at its own time?

Or, when generating StateMachine, do I have to prepare in advance the data parameters that may be used in all processes?

Please tell me some information, Thanks.